# unwanted semicolon in output (php heredoc sytax)

Tags: php

I have the following code. When parsed into the browser I am getting a semicolon right in front of the `<td>` in the first row of the table. I have placed a capital "X" in the code to show exactly where the semicolon shows up. I have tried deleting the white space etc., there are no semicolons in the code or leaking in from the style sheet. Can anyone identify the problem? Thanks.

```
$tableheader=<<<abc
    <br/><div id="divContainer">
<table class="formatHTML5">
<colgroup>
    <col width="5%">
    <col width="15%">
    <col width="15%">
    <col width="15%">
    <col width="30%">
    <col width="15%">
    <col width="5%">
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
        X<td colspan="7" style="font-size:14px"><b>Hi $first you have $recsout searches available this month<br/>Type the Phrase in the Appropriate Search Engine and Answer the Question<br/>Click on Next Term<br/>Click Logoff at any time to save your session if you cannot finish in one sitting</b></td>
    </tr>
............................etc. etc. 
abc; 

__________________________________________________________________
HERE IS THE OUTPUT AS RENDERED:

X;
Hi jack you have 10 searches available this month
Type the Phrase in the Appropriate Search Engine and Answer the Question
Click on Next Term
Click Logoff at any time to save your session if you cannot finish in one    sitting
```

Comment: Shouldn't the terminator be `abc;`, not `abc:`? Can you show an example of the rendered HTML (get it from *View Source*, not the *Elements* tab of your inspection tools)?

Comment: Also, you have an unclosed `<p>` tag and block level elements like `<p>` should not be nested within `<b>`

Comment: What about $first and $recsout? What is the content?

Comment: the heredoc termniatior was a semicolon, my mistake and I took out the p tag and provided the output as rendered.